# Grails - "Cannot get property 'grails' on null object" from unit test

Tags: unit-testing, grails, service, controller, installation

I get the following error...

```
Cannot get property 'grails' on null object
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'grails' on null object
    at pcc.EmailSharerController.<init>(EmailSharerController.groovy)
    at grails.test.MvcUnitTestCase.newInstance(MvcUnitTestCase.groovy:102)
    at grails.test.ControllerUnitTestCase.super$6$newInstance(ControllerUnitTestCase.groovy)
    at grails.test.ControllerUnitTestCase.newInstance(ControllerUnitTestCase.groovy:112)
    at grails.test.ControllerUnitTestCase.setUp(ControllerUnitTestCase.groovy:55)
    at pcc.EmailSharerControllerTests.super$7$setUp(EmailSharerControllerTests.groovy)
    at pcc.EmailSharerControllerTests.setUp(EmailSharerControllerTests.groovy:12)
```

...when I run the unit test setUp() of my `EmailSharerController`, even when it is reduced to this:

```
protected void setUp() {
        super.setUp()  
}
```

I have browsed the web and found nothing. 
I do not any guess from where it could come. 
Any help greatly apreciated :)

Comment: It would help to see your controller. It looks like you're probably referencing  a property of something that's not wired up during unit tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that Grails does not support the ConfigurationHolder object in unit tests. 
It is possible to solve it this way:

```
mockConfig("""  
        grails {
            serverURL = 'my domain name'
        }
    """)
```

to call the `grails.serverURL` property of Config.groovy for example.